# Else without If & Next without For in Vba Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to learn vba excel. With below code I want that the sheet 1 (A1:C8) will be filled with numbers [1-24].
I'm getting the following errors: Else without If and Next without For

```
   Public Sub InsertNummer()
   Worksheets("sheet1").Activate
   Dim Count, RO, CL As Integer
   For CL = 1 To 3 Step 1
   For RO = 1 To 8 Step 1
   
   If CL = 1 Then
   
      For Count = 1 To 8 Step 1
         Cells(RO, CL).Value = Count
      
   ElseIf CL = 2 Then
      For Count = 9 To 16 Step 1
         Cells(RO, CL).Value = Count
         
   Else
      For Count = 17 To 24 Step 1
         Cells(RO, CL).Value = Count
   
   End If
   Next Count
   Next RO
   Next CL
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Your `For` loops need a `Next` inside of the `If` statements.... if that's how you want it structured. Otherwise, you need the full `If` statement inside of the loop it's pertinent to. Also, you have 5 `For` loops started, and only 3 matching `Next` statements. If you are trying to use different ranges for your loop, then determine those variables first, and then use those variables instead of the numbers in a single loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to spend some more time looking through how `For` Loops work correctly.
They really are quite basic and easy to learn but I've got you a code here which is much simpler to achieve the same results:

```
Sub InsertNumber()

Dim CL As Long, RO As Long, Count As Long

Count = 1

For CL = 1 To 3 'Columns 1 to 3
    For RO = 1 To 8 'Rows 1 to 8
        Cells(RO, CL) = Count
        Count = Count + 1
    Next RO
Next CL

End Sub
```

With Loops or If statements, they need to be ended in the order they were started.
So for an if statement in a for loop within an if statement you do:

```
If ...
    For ...
        If ...
        Elseif ...
        Else ...
        End If 
    Next
End If
```

The structure needs to be kept like that.